# Play Scala Template Bug

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

When I import a no-param template from file.scala.html and then call it, I get this rendered in the HTML for each call:

```
BaseScalaTemplate(play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat$@e942bf)
```

^ What is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. In play templates, if you forget the "()" parenthesis, it returns the address of the template in memory.

Comment: The parenthesis '()' should be applied to the call of template. Call template as a method without parameters. I am commenting this as somewhere I saw that the first line of template contains @() which can be ambiguous to this answer and can be helpful to other developers :)